# ASP.NET MVC actionresult multiple pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I currently have a Products controller with a hardcoded 'Product' actionresult per product (as the products are fixed and do not change):

```
site.com/Products/Product 
site.com/nl/Products/Product
```

This results in a single page per product containing all information.
Now I would like to create multiple pages per product to highlight some features or options instead of showing a single product page.

e.g.:

```
site.com/nl/Products/Product/Detail1
site.com/nl/Products/Product/Option2
site.com/nl/Products/Product/Option16
```

What is the best way to do this?

Should I create e.g. ProductDetail1 action and a ProductOption2 action?

Comment: I have done it in a way as: I stored the view name in my database along with the product details. then I made a single action method and get the id of the option clicked by the user as a parameter in the action. and on the basis of Id I return the View("name from database")

Comment: If your option is just string param than you can change your `RouteConfig` for this. Can you show more details of how you want to use theese params?

Comment: @teo: I don't have an idea on how to implement it as I don't know how this could be done. Any suggestions and code examples are welcome..

Awais: I'm not going to store this in a DB.

Comment: Do you use viewModels? What's the relationship between `Product` and `Detail1` or `Product` and `Option2`?

Comment: currently i just have Product1() actionresult Product2() actionresult in my ProductsController.  I just want to create per product some extra pages, which may be different per product. Should I just pass a string in the url, do a switch-statement and return partialviews for each corresponding string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you have your Controller Method:

```
public class ProductsController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Product(string option)
    {
        //here your logic
        return View();
    }
}
```

You can change your Default Route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{option}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", option = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Now if you call url like `site.com/nl/Products/Product/Detail1` `option` object in your controller will have value `Detail1`. And you can do anything what whould you like with this param.

Comment: Is this the "only" way of implementing it or just the most basic one?

Comment: @juFo that' the common way of creating cute Uri. I think it's just not good to create many different Views for your case unless you have some really havy logic.

Comment: i didn't want to add a database for just e.g. 5 fixed products where now 2 or 3 product pages need more info. If it were 10 items or more I would have changed strategoy to a database I think.

Comment: @juFo can't understand you. there is no DB at all in my answer

Comment: (was thinking like Awais Mahmood his comment, nevermind)

Answer (score 1):

You can responce different views in a single action

```
public class ProductsController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Product(int id, string view,)
    {
       Product prod = Context.GetProduct(id);
       if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(view))
       {
            switch(view.ToLower()){
                 case "detail": return View("Detail", prod.Detail);
                 case "option1": return View("Option1", prod.GetOption(1));
                 case "option2": return View("Option2", prod.GetOption(2));
             }
        }
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm going to use the switch to set a ViewData and in my single view load different partialview for each Detail/Option1/Option2 I think this might be better (?)

Comment: This can be a solution too, but if you need to pass a different model in every view then you must pass all models together and split them in the Switch-View rather in Action